# Adding attribute to a user when register in Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel

When a user Register, I want to add location data for the user.
I get those with GeoIP.

So, each time a user is created, I would like somewhere to add Country, City, etc.

I was thinking about setting Hidden fields in view, but I think it a hugly way to do it, and I'm sure there is a better way to do...

Any Idea???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using Request Contructor as said here in [laracast](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/how-do-i-add-an-input-value-on-the-fly-inside-a-request-instance)

In the Form Request's constructor I inject \Illuminate\Http\Request. I can then add my value to the request instance as such:

```
public function __construct(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
{
    $request->request->add(['date_of_birth' => implode('-', $request->only('year', 'month', 'day'))]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Any time I create a record that needs extra data, involves inserting additional records into additional tables, etc, I create a service class. Something like "UserCreator" then I pass it the input, do any additional operations, wrap multiple database calls in a transaction and so on.

That said there are so many ways to do what you want. You could Input::merge(...) then save, you could separate the process of creating a user from your controller / route function, etc.

If you are just getting started with Laravel and/or your project is rather simple, then you probably want to look at Input::merge